# I want to use enum in macro

Tags: c

```
enum ArgPos

{
P1 = 1,
P2 = 2,
P3 = 3
};

void fun(int, int, int);

#define FUN(ArgPos, ArgPos, ArgPos) fun(ArgPos, ArgPos, ArgPos)

int main(void)

{

FUN(P1, P2, P3);
return 0;
}

void fun(int a, int b, int c)
{
 printf("fun");
}
```

Comment: If any answer answered your question, please "accept" it by pressing the "v" next to it (-;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the define (if you really write it like that) have an error using the same name for args

should be

```
#define FUN(ArgPos1, ArgPos2, ArgPos3) fun(ArgPos1, ArgPos2, ArgPos3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You named both the `enum` and the macro parameters the same.

You need:

```
#define FUN(x,y,z) fun(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is not with enums but with your macro:

```
#define FUN(x,y,z) fun(x,y,z)
```